# Why is this cart index view (Razor engine) giving me errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

It does not seem to like @{index++;} , I have tried
@{int index++}, @(index++), @(int index++;)

This code didn't throw errors when used with MVC 2.
Here's it's giving me
ambiguity warnings about index.

```
@model CartTest.Models.Cart

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Cart Index</h2>


<table width="80%" align="center">


<thead><tr>
<th align="center">Quantity</th>
<th align="left">Item</th>
<th align="right">Price</th>
<th align="right">Subtotal</th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>


@{int index = 0;}

@foreach (var line in Model.Lines)
{
<tr>
@Html.Hidden("Lines.Index", index);
<td align="center">@Html.TextBox("Lines[" + index + "].Quantity",line.Quantity)</td>
<td align="left">@line.Product.Name</td>
<td align="right">@line.Product.Price</td>
<td align="right">@(line.Quantity * line.Product.Price)</td>
<td align="right">@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveItem", new { productId = line.Product.ProductID }, null)</td>

</tr>

@{index++;}    

}

</tbody>


<tfoot>


</tfoot>


</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@{int index = 0;}
@foreach (var line in Model.Lines)
{
    <tr>
       ...
    </tr>
    index++;
}
```

Now that's just to make the Razor compiler happy. It's not a solution I recommend. The real solution I would recommend you is to use editor templates:

```
<table width="80%" align="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th align="center">Quantity</th>
        <th align="left">Item</th>
        <th align="right">Price</th>
        <th align="right">Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Lines)
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

and inside the corresponding editor template of a Line (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/LineViewModel.cshtml`) which will be rendered for each element of the Line collection:

```
@model LineViewModel
<td align="center">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity)
</td>
<td align="left">
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Product.Name)
</td>
<td align="right">
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Product.Price)
</td>
<td align="right">
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CalculatedTotalPrice) 
</td>
<td align="right">
    @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveItem", new { productId = Model.Product.ProductID }, null)
</td>
```

See, no more ugly loops, weakly typed helpers, dealing with some indexes, etc... Everything works by conventions.

Comment: Thanks, now it works but I am getting ";" left over with each item I put in the cart WTF! And using just "index++" gives an error. Seems Razor is full of bugs.

Comment: @LaserBeak, no you are doing something wrong. The `;` you are seeing comes from some other part of your code. Razor is not full of bugs. It's the best view engine ever created. Ahh, see this: `Html.Hidden("Lines.Index", index);`. See the `;` at the end? Now remove it. Happy? Of course if you follow my advice and use editor templates you wouldn't ever care about any hidden fields and stuff. Your code will simply become nice and clean.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks. It seems my eyes are full of bugs now, gotta get some rest :) And so with those editor templates, I don't need to keep index for even when I need to update quantity of cart items from the client ?

Comment: Anywhere I can read up on using editor templates as such. Because Model.Lines is a List of CartLine Objects (CartLine has two properties Product product and int Quantity) and MVC just can't create scaffolding automatically for a collection of CartLine objects it seems.